# Package installation in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, zip

How shall I directly install a .zip package without actually unzipping it in Ubuntu 18.04?

I am trying to install m2tex.

Comment: You shan't. Unpack it and you'll probably find instructions inside. Or at the website you downloaded it from.

Comment: A .zip is NOT a package. It's merely a .zip, and could contain anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @GabrielaGarcia mentioned, a .zip package isn't really a software archive that can be installed using package management tools. Instead, it is a simple archive containing files. Often, after unzipping the file, there will be a file describing how to use these files, e.g. README.txt. I would not expect to be able to install this without unzipping it first.

In your case, a quick google brought up several hits for m2tex that appears to suggest it is a fairly simple Matlab script/tool. In cases like this, there will often not be a file describing how to install. Instead, the maker of the software assumes you know how to import the script into Matlab.

To unzip the archive either double click on the icon using the file manager or type `unzip filename.zip` in the appropriate directory at the command line.

If the m2tex you are attempting to install is not the Matlab script I found, please give us some more information. Such as: where did you get the file? What are the contents of the file? Any additional information you can provide will help me or others to give you better information.

It is possible that Matlab imports .zip archives from a script folder automatically, if that is the case you may find more help on the Matlab forum.

The link you provided appears to state how to use the script:
1) Unzip the archive wherever you want it, likely in your home directory.
2) Open the file in Matlab and run it.

Comment: This is the link from where I downloaded this Matlab to Latex code converter.                                                                                  https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24515-m-code-to-latex-converter